# fatal error in integration of MATLAB code and C/C++

Tags: c++, matlab, fatal-error, matlab-engine

I used a sample code from mathworks website to integrate a MATLAB code with C/C++ by [a link](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/apiref/rmvd_matlablink__4b82b61395ba0923d01ae0286cf41dc7.html)!

As you seen in the code, there is header file as: 
`#include "engine.h"`

In Linux (Ubuntu), I ran:
`g++ engdemo.cpp -o mycpp` command to create an executable program, but the below fatal error occurred:

> engdemo.cpp:14:20: fatal error: engine.h: No such file or directory, compilation terminated.

How can i solve this fatal error?

Comment: Does `engine.h` file exists in the current directory?

Comment: @BlueBit: you need to tell the compiler where to find the header files. You also need to link against the required libraries. The documentation explains this: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/compiling-engine-applications-with-the-mex-command.html , http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-1BSZR/

Answer (score 2):

Look in

```
[matlabroot '/extern/include']
```

If you see `engine.h` there, just run

```
g++ -I../../include engdemo.cpp -o mycpp
```

(assuming you run from `[matlabroot '/extern/examples/eng_mat/']`)

Comment: There is an error when run: g++ -I /usr/local/MATLAB/R2011b/extern/include engdemo.cpp -o mycpp :
/tmp/ccNSRT82.o: In function `main':
engdemo.cpp:(.text+0x4c): undefined reference to `engOpen'
engdemo.cpp:(.text+0xa7): undefined reference to `mxCreateDoubleMatrix'
engdemo.cpp:(.text+0xb7): undefined reference to `mxGetPr'
engdemo.cpp:(.text+0x141): undefined reference to `engPutVariable'
engdemo.cpp:(.text+0x155): undefined reference to `engEvalString'
engdemo.cpp:(.text+0x169): undefined reference to `engEvalString'
engdemo.cpp:(.text+0x17d): undefined reference to `engEvalString' ...